# How to reset HTML input fields if I don't know beforehand how many inputs there will be?

Tags: reactjs

Any ideas how to reset input fields when they are dynamically generated? Couldn't find any information about this. If I would know in advance how many fields there will be it would be easy with `ref` or just have unique `value` attributes on every `input` element and the call `getInitialState()`.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15407/

Size of the product array can vary so how would you reset all of the input fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your (uncontrolled) inputs in a HTML `<form>` element, there's always

```
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
```

Otherwise, you'll probably want to bind the input value to a `prop` or `state` item, and then use handleReset to retrieve and (re)set these values. When an item in state or prop changes, React will automatically update the affected parts of your DOM.

Read more about form inputs in the docs: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

you can set `this.setState` by array of values

https://jsfiddle.net/amb223fx/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As mgrim said, you can use HTML form reset. Or, if you need something more sophisticated, keep reading.

Take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ycr0ErKCM1tkjJqzKhP?p=preview):

```
var products = [
    {name: 'Chocolate'}, 
  {name: 'Chips'}, 
  {name: 'Candy'}
];
// Size of the products array can vary!

var Hello = React.createClass({
    handleReset: function(){
    var products = this.state.products.map(function (product) {
      return Object.assign({}, product, {
        value: 0
      });
    });
    this.setState({products: products});
  },
  handleChange: function(index){
    return function(e){
      var products = this.state.products.slice();
      var product = products[index];
      products[index] = Object.assign({}, product, {
          value: parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
        });
        this.setState({products: products});
    }.bind(this);
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      products: this.props.initialProducts.map(function (product) {
        return {
          name: product.name,
          value: 0
        }
      })
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var prods = this.state.products.map(function(item, id){
        return (
        <li key={id}>
            {item.name}
          <input type="number" value={item.value} onChange={this.handleChange(id)} />
        </li>
      )
    }.bind(this));
    return (
        <ul>
        {prods}
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Hello initialProducts={products} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

You'll have to call `setState` every time there is a change in any of the input boxes, and `setState` when the user intends to reset all inputs.

Also, I did some refactoring. I renamed the `products` property to `initialProducts` property. This is because [assigning a property to a state is an anti-pattern, unless we clarify that the inputed property will be a part of the state that will change over time](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).

Answer (score -1):

The idea here is just to get all input and use a for to clean them up. Please note that I'm using Jquery to get all inputs.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function cleanForm(){    
         var allInputs = $( ":input" );
         for (i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) { 
           allInputs[i].value = ""; 
         }
      }   
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form> 
        <input type="text" name="1"/>
        <input type="text" name="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="3"/>
        <input type="text" name="4"/>
        <input type="button" name="clean" onclick="cleanForm()" value="clean"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you explain what your function do, please. Only a piece of code is not a good answer. Also the OP doesn't mention the use of jQuery.

Comment: Not to mention, that solution isn't answering OP's question. His issue is more related to React than just plain HTML+JS.